# CPLEX Optimization: program freezes

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to code my math model in CPLEX but when it gets to the one of my constraints it freezes. I am prety sure that problem is the variable M[cc]. here the code:

```
//Constraint 9
for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++)
    for (rr = 0; rr < AvailableRooms; rr++)
        for (ss = 0; ss < AvailableTimeSlots; ss++) {
            mod.add((1 - Y[cc][rr])*(-BigM) + Distance[rr][ss] <= M[cc] + (1 - Y[cc][ss])*(BigM));
            cout << M[cc];
            
        }
```

here is how i defined mentioned parameters and variables:

```
long int BigM = 100000;
double Distance[AvailableRooms][AvailableRooms];

//Ycr
IloBoolVarArray2 Y(env, NumberOfCourses);
for (cc = 0; cc < NumberOfCourses; cc++)
    Y[cc] = IloBoolVarArray(env, AvailableRooms);

IloNumVarArray M(env, NumberOfCourses, 0, IloInfinity);
```

here is the output of M[cc] before it freezes:

IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf] IloNumVar(20311)[0 .. inf]

explanation about variable M[cc]: this variable representing the maximum distance between rooms r and s for course c which in the constraint we want to make sure Distance[rr][ss] is less than the max distance.

I am stuck why it gives me an error? should I define M[cc] in other ways?

Comment: You declare the array `double Distance[AvailableRooms][AvailableRooms]` but handle it in the loop as an array `double Distance[AvailableRooms][AvailableTimeSlots]`.

Comment: yup. I just figured that out. thank you.

Comment: NB: Do you know that you may also write your model in OPL CPLEX which is simpler and then embed your model in some C++ ?

Comment: Or just stick with doing it in C++ and Concert and avoid having to learn OPL. Then it's all just C++ code.